# Expressing ''shoulda, coulda, woulda"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/woulda,_coulda,_shoulda
>
> An expression of dismissiveness or disappointment concerning a statement, question, explanation, course of action, or occurrence involving hypothetical possibilities, uncertain facts, or missed opportunities.(This stems from expressing that someone could have, would have and/or should have done something)

Is there any idiomatic way to express in French something like

> There's nothing worse than shoulda, coulda, woulda. (i.e. Spare me the useless excuses)

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve parfois les phonétiques :

> Yfalé, Yavéka, Yoréfalu, Yakafokon...

C'est à dire :

- Y fallait (Il fallait)
- Y'avait qu'à (Il n'y avait qu'à)
- Y'aurait fallu (Il aurait fallu)
- Y'a qu'à, faut qu'on (Il n'y a qu'a, il faut qu'on)

Comment: It would probably be profitable to spell out the phrases being played on... Il fallait, il y avait cas, il aurait fallu, il y a cas (où il) faut qu'on - -?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Done! Thanks.

Comment: Une recherche sur "vocabulaire des chefs" vous en donnera un paquet dans la même image...